# Javascript obfuscation with BundleTransformer.UglifyJs

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, bundle, obfuscation

I just added the [BundleTransformer.UglifyJs NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BundleTransformer.UglifyJs/1.8.29) to my MVC project to obfuscate javascript code.

But the result just looks not very ugly:

```
function onDeckenstaerkeChanged(){validateCorrectDeckenstaerke();$("#dropdown-bta").empty();$.each(getBelagtraegerAbstand(
```

This is the part in my web.config where the minifier is configured:

```
<bundleTransformer xmlns="http://tempuri.org/BundleTransformer.Configuration.xsd">
    <core>
        <css>
            <minifiers>
                <add name="NullMinifier" type="BundleTransformer.Core.Minifiers.NullMinifier, BundleTransformer.Core" />
              <add name="YuiCssMinifier" type="BundleTransformer.Yui.Minifiers.YuiCssMinifier, BundleTransformer.Yui" /></minifiers>
            <translators>
                <add name="NullTranslator" type="BundleTransformer.Core.Translators.NullTranslator, BundleTransformer.Core" enabled="false" />
            </translators>
        </css>
        <js defaultMinifier="UglifyJsMinifier">
    <minifiers>
      <add name="NullMinifier" type="BundleTransformer.Core.Minifiers.NullMinifier, BundleTransformer.Core" />
      <add name="YuiJsMinifier" type="BundleTransformer.Yui.Minifiers.YuiJsMinifier, BundleTransformer.Yui" />
      <add name="UglifyJsMinifier" type="BundleTransformer.UglifyJs.Minifiers.UglifyJsMinifier, BundleTransformer.UglifyJs" />
    </minifiers>
    <translators>
      <add name="NullTranslator" type="BundleTransformer.Core.Translators.NullTranslator, BundleTransformer.Core" enabled="false" />
    </translators>
  </js>
    </core>
</bundleTransformer>
```

For me the result looks minfied, but not obfuscated.

What do I miss and what should the result look like?

Is there a way to debug which module is used?

Answer (score 4):

As stated [here](https://bundletransformer.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Bundle%20Transformer%201.9.18#BundleTransformerUglifyJs_Chapter):

> As a JS-engine is used the JavaScript Engine Switcher library. For correct working of this module is recommended to install one of the following NuGet packages: [JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Msie](http://nuget.org/packages/JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Msie) or  [JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.V8](http://nuget.org/packages/JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.V8). After package is installed, need set a name of JavaScript engine (for example, MsieJsEngine) to the name attribute of /configuration/bundleTransformer/uglify/jsEngine configuration element.

for bundle transformer UglifyJS to work, you need JS-engine installed and in your web.config snippet I don't see it defined. Therefore, install [JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Msie](http://nuget.org/packages/JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Msie) or [JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.V8](http://nuget.org/packages/JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.V8) package.

#### Important!

Depending on which package you install, you'll have to manually add at the end of your web.config snippet for V8:

```
...
</core>
  <uglify>
    <jsEngine name="V8JsEngine"></jsEngine>
  </uglify>
</bundleTransformer>
```

or for MsieJsEngine:

```
...
</core>
  <uglify>
    <jsEngine name="MsieJsEngine"></jsEngine>
  </uglify>
</bundleTransformer>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `onDeckenstaerkeChanged` function is global, and therefore it's name is not processed.

You need to make it local. To do this, wrap the code in a IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression):

```
(function(){
    ...
    function onDeckenstaerkeChanged(){
        ...
    }
    ...
})();
```

There is another variant. If you enable the `mangling.topLevel` option, then you can obfuscate all global variables. In the `mangling.except` option you can specify the names of variables, that do not need to apply obfuscation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <bundleTransformer xmlns="http://tempuri.org/BundleTransformer.Configuration.xsd">
        ...
        <uglify>
            <js ...>
                <mangling topLevel="true" except="$,ko,myVar" />
            </js>
            ...
        </uglify>
        ...
    </bundleTransformer>
</configuration>
```